# Hebrew characters in play framework are not shown

Tags: playframework, hebrew

I am using play framework with pdf module. I am using render pdf BUT only English characters are shown.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you’re talking about Hebrew characters in PDF output, the problem is probably that you’re not specifying a PDF font that contains Hebrew characters.

On web pages, we’re used to web browsers performing automatic font substitution to select characters that are not available in the current font. PDF output doesn’t do that.

If you want to support lots of languages in PDF output, then you either need to choose a font that supports many sets such as the [M+ fonts](http://mplus-fonts.sourceforge.jp/mplus-outline-fonts/index-en.html) we use for http://plancruncher.com (built in Play). Alternatively, select a font based on user language selection.

Comment: Where should I define the font sets? in the CSS? in the HTML? or in the backend? that is what i defined in the CSS '@importurl(http://fonts.googleapis.com/earlyaccess/alefhebrew.css);

Comment: I'm guessing that defines a webfont, and that that's not supported by the PDF renderer. Try a local font on the server.